# How to force a kernel update on Debian

Tags: debian, kernel, debian-stretch

I recently upgraded from Wheezy to Stretch.
Now MySQL (MariaDB) isn't starting due to an outdated kernel.

The output of `uname -r` is: `3.2.0-4-amd64`

The list of installed kernels is:

```
# dpkg -l | grep linux-image
ii  linux-image-2.6-amd64                 3.2+46+deb7u2                     amd64        Linux for 64-bit PCs (dummy package)
rc  linux-image-2.6.32-5-amd64            2.6.32-48squeeze6                 amd64        Linux 2.6.32 for 64-bit PCs
rc  linux-image-3.16.0-6-amd64            3.16.57-2                         amd64        Linux 3.16 for 64-bit PCs
ii  linux-image-3.2.0-4-amd64             3.2.96-2                          amd64        Linux 3.2 for 64-bit PCs
rc  linux-image-3.2.0-5-amd64             3.2.96-3                          amd64        Linux 3.2 for 64-bit PCs
rc  linux-image-3.2.0-6-amd64             3.2.102-1                         amd64        Linux 3.2 for 64-bit PCs
ii  linux-image-4.9.0-8-amd64             4.9.110-3+deb9u4                  amd64        Linux 4.9 for 64-bit PCs
ii  linux-image-amd64                     4.9+80+deb9u6                     amd64        Linux for 64-bit PCs (meta-package)
```

When I try to install it, I get that:

```
# apt install linux-image-4.9.0-8-amd64
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
linux-image-4.9.0-8-amd64 is already the newest version (4.9.110-3+deb9u4).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

What do I have to do to force the kernel update?

Comment: This question belongs to [Unix & Linux.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was an outdated boot menu. The new kernel was not there.

After installing `grub2` with `apt install grub2`, I could use `update-grub`.

In the file `/etc/default/grub` the GRUB_DEFAULT was set to 0, so the first item in the boot menu is used.
The boot menu was updated and the new kernel was on top.

After `reboot` the new kernel was used.